# How could I change the package name when I wanna upload apk or aab file to google play store?

Tags: android, firebase

How could I change the package name when I wanna upload apk or aab file to google play store?

Because I changed my google developer account, but I had upload aab file to my old google account before. Now I need to upload aab file to new google account, when I change the applicationId package name and I running app I get the error. I have use firebase realtime database.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name
```

So how can I do it?

Comment: this is an error caused by the firebase sdk(google-service.json) that was installed in the app. The package name/s in you (google-services.json) is not matching with the one stated in you build.gradle file. You can never generate aab or apk if they are not a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your application ID, you also need to repeat the steps that you originally took to [create an app in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#console).  That app needs to use your new application ID.  Then, you will need to use the new Firebase configuration in your app project.

It's not possible to reuse your old Firebase app configuration if you change your app ID.  You must create a new Firebase app in the console.

Comment: so how can move date to new firebase app?

Comment: If you are creating a second app in the same project, it shares all the same data with the first app.  You don't have to do anything.  If you are creating a whole new project, then you will have to copy things on your own.

Comment: it's same app, I just want to change to new google developer account. But the package name already in google play store, I cannot upload to my new google developer account.

Comment: It's not possible to change an application ID that was already uploaded to the play store.  You will need to build and upload a new app.  That has nothing to do with Firebase.  It's a requirement of the play store.